# Python stderr redirect to file

Tags: python, redirect, stderr, pi

I'm trying to redirect stderr to a file, and I've read the numerous posts here, but it's not working for me on a Pi or on my Win laptop.
Hoping someone will see what's wrong.

Using IDLE -

On Pi, the file is written but is empty, and stderr (traceback - /0) wasn't written to the IDLE shell....

On Win, the file is written but is empty, and stderr (traceback - /0 ) still appears in the IDLE shell.

```
import sys
import time

sys.stderrr = open('errout.txt', 'w')
print("stderr redirected now.")

i = 1/0
```

Comment: You have a typo.  You have too many r's in `stderrr`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `stderrr` to `stderr` and you should be okay